# C++ Using features of a newer compiler to generate code for use by an older compiler

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, c++14, c++03

I've been looking into some of the features of the "newer" C++ standards (C++11 and C++14), and that got me thinking about something. I'm currently using the VC++2008 compiler for my projects (for various reasons), which means that the newest standard I have access to is C++03, plus TR1. TR1 has some nice things in it, but there are features in C++11 and C++14 that would be nice to have.

My question is this: Would there be any way that I could build some code using a newer compiler (say MSVC2012 or 2013) to build libraries or DLLs using the newer C++11 and C++14 functionality and then link that into my project that's running the '08 compiler?

The only thing that I could think of that wouldn't work would be anywhere I had to have a C++11 or C++14 feature in a header included by my '08 compiler project. However as long as everything "new" were hidden behind my interface, shouldn't this work?

Comment: Beware of having two or more runtime libraries interacting confusingly...

Comment: C++ compilers in general are not binary compatible to each other. You can´t link eg. a MinGW C++ dll to VS, independent of the used C++ standard. Only VS with VS. So no, you can´t get unsupported features in VS. (And it doesn´t fully support C++03. Not even C99.). As paulm said below now, C interfaces are compatible (well, "somewhat". It´s VS), but not C++

Comment: @deviantfan GCC is binary compatible (bar a few corner cases and rogue versions.)

Comment: @juanchopanza G++ (with C++) bin.comp. to VS? That would be great, but somehow it´s hard to believe...

Comment: @deviantfan No, between its own c++98 and C++11 versions.

Comment: @juanchopanza Well, ok ... but why is that relevant here?

Comment: @deviantfan It is a side note to your statement "C++ compilers in general are not binary compatible..."

Comment: Also, VS breaks binary compatibility with each major release.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes but its going to get ugly.. since the ABI is not compatible you'll have to go down to the "`extern "C" {}`" ABIness.

That means you can't pass C++ objects at all.. like I said, painful. It also means it must be a DLL since you won't be able to link in a static lib with another ABI.

Its up to you if its worth wrapping up a DLL in a C API just to use a couple of new features or not, I would recommend just upgraded the whole project though.

I almost forgot, you probably can't link the import lib either, so you'll have to have some code that uses `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress` and `FreeLibrary` (did I mention this is ugly/painful?).

Comment: So I assume that means that if I have a piece of hardware and I want to write an API so that other people can communicate with my hardware I'm either stuck writing the toolkit in C or providing the C++ source?

Comment: @IanM: No. You can provide a C toolkit that is actually written in C++, and use all the C++ goodies like smart pointers internally. It's only the functions called from outside your library that have to use pure C signatures.

Comment: Yeah this is why its quite a bit of extra work, you'd have C++98 wrapper -> C API -> C++11

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you're trying to do is not possible with MSVC. They intentionally break binary compatibility with every major release as stated in [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx):

> To enable new optimizations and debugging checks, the Visual Studio implementation of the C++ Standard Library **intentionally breaks binary compatibility from one version to the next**. Therefore, when the C++ Standard Library is used, object files and static libraries that are compiled by using different versions can't be mixed in one binary (EXE or DLL), and C++ Standard Library objects can't be passed between binaries that are compiled by using different versions. Such mixing emits linker errors about _MSC_VER mismatches. (_MSC_VER is the macro that contains the compiler's major version—for example, 1800 for Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2013.) **This check cannot detect DLL mixing, and cannot detect mixing that involves Visual C++ 2008 or earlier.**

Your options are to then only pass around POD types, or implement COM interfaces to interop between the DLLs compiled using different version of the VC compiler, neither of which is particularly palatable.

My advice would be, if you must stick with VS2008 for certain legacy applications, suck it up and deal with the feature set it supports (at least you have TR1). For newer projects, try and talk your team into using newer versions of VC.

Comment: *"Your options are to then only pass around POD types"* Does MSDN say that the memory layout of user-defined types (that don't use StdLib) changes, or the vtable layout?

Comment: @dyp Yeah, the linked page talks about that - *although POD (plain old data) object layout and COM interfaces are guaranteed not to break from version to version, other kinds of object layout—for example, in scenarios that involve inheritance or template instantiation—are subject to change.* So vtable layout is something that could change.

Comment: COM interface compatibility guarantees that v-table layout *can't* change

Comment: @BenVoigt I'll have to take your word on that, I have no experience dealing with COM. So why are they listing inheritance as one of the things that could break ABI compatibility then?

Comment: @Praetorian: Hmm, there are two things going on here.  Remember that the vtable isn't part of each object, there's only a pointer to it, the vfptr, which in COM and compatible C++ compilers is always at the very beginning of the (sub)object.  So the table layout is compatible, but not necessarily the relative spacing and ordering of subobjects in an object with multiple inheritance, as COM objects generally have.

Comment: @Praetorian: Also consider that moving from one vfptr to another is the work of `IUnknown::QueryInterface`, which is implemented by the object itself, so it has knowledge of the full layout.  A COM client can't do that operation itself, because the subobject placement isn't standardized (and then there are tearoff interfaces...).